# Подскажите пожалуйста, как отсортировать коллекцию set в обратном порядке и вывести? я положил лист в сет, а дальше не знаю(можно любой сет)

Tags: java, сортировка, коллекции, set

```java
import java.util.*;

public class StackNumbers {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
        numbers.add(99);
        numbers.add(9);
        numbers.add(99);
        numbers.add(999);
        Collections.sort(numbers);

        for (Integer num : numbers) {
            System.out.println(num);
        }
        Set<Integer> dig = new TreeSet<>(numbers);
    }
}
```

Comment: Коллекция вида set уже являются отсортированными по своим правилам и просто так отсортировать нельзя. Но можно обычно задать свой компаратор

Comment: знаешь почему минусуют!? этот вопрос гуглится за 2 минуты

Comment: Когда знаешь ответ, то да, гуглится очень быстро. А вот если не знать, то найти сложно

Comment: возможно) но можно было б немного почитать про TreeSet и понять что не получится

Comment: А его что, можно сортировать?:)

Comment: не то написал) просто вопрос зачем сет, если если это отлично в листе делается?

Comment: Некрасиво менять свой коммент, когда указали на ошибку:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если используется `TreeSet`, то для получения множества, отсортированного в обратном порядке, достаточно воспользоваться методом [`TreeSet::descendingSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#descendingSet--), но нужно использовать конкретную реализацию при определении типа `dig`:

```java
TreeSet<Integer> dig = new TreeSet<>(numbers);
System.out.println(dig.descendingSet()); // -> [999, 99, 9]
```

---

Если *очень нужно* получить сразу же сет в обратном порядке, следует использовать конструктор [`TreeSet(Comparator<? super E> comparator)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#TreeSet-java.util.Comparator-), а затем добавить все элементы коллекции при помощи `addAll`:

```java
Set<Integer> reverse = new TreeSet<>(Comparator.reverseOrder());
reverse.addAll(numbers);

System.out.println(reverse); // -> [999, 99, 9]
```

Answer (score 2):

у сета нет дубликатов.
можно вывести в обратном порядке используя stream api

```
 dig.stream().sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder()).forEach(System.out::println);
```